# Query to count data where meet specific condition

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a problem to count c1 where they have a1 and a2 and count a1 and a2 alone.

```
C1 | C2
_______ 
a  | a1
a  | a2
b  | a1
b  | a2
c  | a1
d  | a2
```

Result.

```
a1 | a1 & a2 | a2       ---> from C2
________________
1 |     2     | 1         ---> from C1
```

I want to count where value from c1 have 2 value from c2.

Comment: Please provide logic for your output ?

Comment: Please share your schema and raw data with input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query.

```
   select [a1], [a1&a2],[a2] 
from
(
  SELECT DISTINCT t2.c2 AS C2,COUNT(*) as col FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table1 t2 ON  t1.c1=t2.c1 GROUP BY t2.c2,t2.c1 HAVING COUNT(*)<2 
UNION ALL
select distinct
   LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(stuff((SELECT distinct '& ' + cast(c2 as varchar(10))
           FROM Table1 t2
           where t2.c1 = t1.c1
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),'&amp; ','&'),'amp;','')) AS C2,Count(*) as col
from Table1 t1 group by c1 HAVING COUNT(*)>1  
) d
pivot
(
  max(col)
  for c2 in ([a1],[a1&a2] ,[a2])
) piv;
```